# JDK Not installing in Debian.

Tags: debian, java, installation

I am using these commands to install JDK/JVM in Debian server:

```
apt-get install openjdk-jdk
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

But getting lots of error:

```
 404 Not Found [IP: 149.20.20.6 80]
 404 Not Found [IP: 199.6.12.70 80]
```

I trying to install this by:

```
apt-cache search jdk
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre
```

But here also showing same problem.

Does anyone know what can be causing this problem?

Comment: which mirror are you using?
can you show contents of /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: Not following mirror?

Comment: Did you remember to run `apt-get update` first to refresh the package lists?

Comment: Yeah I have used this before start JDK.

Comment: What version of Debian?

Comment: Using -  (gcc version 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4) version

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have run `apt-get update` before anything else.

The package name you likely want is `openjdk-6-jdk` or `openjdk-6-jre` (depending on if you are compiling java or just running java.

Debian is no longer distributing sun-* java packages, as oracle has changed the distribution license in a way which makes it illegal for us to do so.

If this is still not working, please show us the output of `apt-cache policy openjdk-6-jre`

Another possibility is that you are running a no longer supported release of Debian, like lenny (5.0) or etch (4.0), which are no longer on the regular Debian mirrors, but on http://archive.debian.org.  Those would have out-dated, security-vulnerable versions of the sun java packages.  However, if this is the case, I'd expect the `apt-get update` command to also give 404 errors.  And if this is your situation, my recommendation is to first upgrade to a currently supported release of Debian.

EDIT:

You comment confirms that you are running an outdated version of debian which is no longer supported and no longer carried on the main mirrors.  Lenny has been moved to the archive mirror on http://archive.debian.org/  On this archive, you will find old, known to be security-vulnerable versions of the JDKs.  You could install these after changing to use the archive mirror, but my strong recommendation is to upgrade to the currently supported release by following the instructions in the [chapter 4 of the squeeze release notes](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html)

Comment: I am getting this by apt-cache policy openjdk-6-jre ---


instead.
domU-12-31-39-07-4A-8D:~# apt-cache policy openjdk-6-jre
openjdk-6-jre:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6b11-9.1+lenny2
  Version table:
     6b11-9.1+lenny2 0
        500 http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main Packages
     6b11-9.1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny/main Packages

Comment: I have used "apt-get update" too but error not solving.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that--it's bitten me before, too! >.<

Answer (score 1):

Do you have network connectivity? It looks like you're having one of three problems.

1. You don't have an internet connection. Ergo `apt-get` (or anything else that downloads files from the network) will not work.
2. You're trying to download the packages from a mirror that's offline. Try checking this by using `apt-get` to download something else.
3. It's possible (but unlikely) that your DNS cache is stale. Flush it using a guide like [this one](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-clearflush-dns-cache-in-ubuntu.html).

You may also be able to get the JDK in an offline form as a `.deb` package, and install it that way. You should be able to find what you'd need [here](http://wiki.debian.org/Java). Once you download the `.deb` package, use the following command to install it:

```
 sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

***Where `packagename.deb` is the name of the package you'd like to install***

Comment: Internet connection is fine every thing is running ok other then this.

Just now I installed tomcat without any problem

Comment: I added an alternate way to get the package installed.

Comment: showing this error-

dpkg: error processing packagename.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packagename.deb

Comment: I assumed you'd know that `packagename.deb` would be the name of the `.deb` file you want to install. Replace `packagename.deb` with the name of the JDK `.deb` file, and it will work.

Comment: Thx, Can you give me any link, how to use this.

Comment: At this point, I've given you the link to the packages (see my post) and the commands you need. Short of doing the install for you, I can't do any more.

Comment: I'd recommend NOT going down this route.  You should fix the underlying problem instead of working around it.  The underlying problem is likely to be causing you to be missing out on security updates, and might just be coming up again the next time you are trying to install a package.

Comment: @stew: good point. Especially with Java.